# What do the alphanumeric names of scripts stand for in the short movie "George Lucas in love"?

Tags: plot-explanation, george-lucas-in-love

I have just rewatched the short *[George Lucas in love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Lucas_in_Love)* (1999) by Joe Nussbaum.

It depicts a young George Lucas trying to write a script for his graduation while the Star Wars world is all around him in the campus.

In this short, all George Lucas' scripts have no actual titles, but only some weird alphanumeric string of characters.

I wonder: **is that a joke I don't get about the star Wars series (or George Lucas himself)? Or is it *just for fun*?**

Comment: Examples would be helpful. If the only one we see is THX-1138, that was [his first feature length film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/THX_1138).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**They're simply telling the truth.** Those were indeed the titles of George Lucas's student films.

[1:42.08](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1:42.08) is a short documentary about a race car driver finishing a lap in 1 minute and 42.08 seconds:

> 1:42.08 (alternatively known as 1:42.08: A Man and His Car or 1:42.08: To Qualify) is George Lucas's senior project at the University of Southern California in 1966. It was named for the lap time of the Lotus 23 race car that was the subject of the film.

[6-18-67](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6-18-67) is another short documentary he shot on a scholarship at the end of his tenure at USC:

> 6-18-67 is a short quasi-documentary film by George Lucas regarding the making of the 1969 Columbia film, [*Mackenna's Gold*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mackenna's_Gold). This nonstory noncharacter visual tone poem is made up of nature imagery, time-lapse photography, and the subtle sounds of the Arizona desert. *Shooting was completed on June 18, 1967.*

Here are both of these films: